# ¿Cómo usar una subconsulta en joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

disculpen necesito tener una funcion que me vaya a traer informacion de varias tablas esto con INNER Y LEFTS JOINS, la consulta funciona y todo, pero tengo el problema que cometi el error de nombrar dos columnas de diferentes tablas con el mismo nombre y al momento que genero la consulta esta me devuelve dos veces art_codigo_interno de tabla A y tabla B, en donde por decirlo art_codigo_interno B deberia ser art_codigo2, podría renombrar el campo de la tabla, pero eso me implica modificar todo mi Backend, cosa que no lo quiero hacer, solo necesito tomar el codigo_interno A.

- ESTE ES EL JOIN QUE ME TRAE LOS DATOS, la tabla se llama inv_articulo_exportacion

  LEFT JOIN inv_articulo_exportacion iae ON iae.art_codigo_interno = ia.art_codigo

+CONSULTA

```
SELECT * FROM vnt_cotizacion vc
INNER JOIN vnt_detalle_cotizacion vdc ON vdc.dven_cotizacion = vc.ven_codigo
INNER JOIN inv_articulo ia ON ia.art_codigo = vdc.dven_articulo 
INNER JOIN inv_categoria icat ON icat.cat_codigo = ia.art_categoria_export 
INNER JOIN inv_marca imar ON imar.mar_codigo = ia.art_marca 
LEFT JOIN inv_categoria_export icex ON icex.id_categoria_export = icat.cat_codigo
LEFT JOIN inv_articulo_exportacion iae ON iae.art_codigo_interno = ia.art_codigo 
LEFT JOIN inv_articulo_cumplimiento cum ON cum.articuloId = ia.art_codigo 
WHERE vc.ven_codigo = 686 AND imar.mar_requiere_doc_exportacion = 1 
ORDER BY ia.art_descripcion ASC
```

- La consulta me genera esto, el codigo interno que aparece en la izquierda es el que necesito
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Entonces yo probe con esto, pero me dice que tengo error de sintaxis, que me podrían aconsejar

  ```
         SELECT * FROM vnt_cotizacion vc
         INNER JOIN vnt_detalle_cotizacion vdc ON vdc.dven_cotizacion = vc.ven_codigo
         INNER JOIN inv_articulo ia ON ia.art_codigo = vdc.dven_articulo 
         INNER JOIN inv_categoria icat ON icat.cat_codigo = ia.art_categoria_export 
         INNER JOIN inv_marca imar ON imar.mar_codigo = ia.art_marca 
         LEFT JOIN inv_categoria_export icex ON icex.id_categoria_export = icat.cat_codigo
         JOIN
        (SELECT iae.art_onzas1, iae.art_onzas2, iae.art_mililitros, iae.art_gramos, iae.marker, iae.adress 
         FROM inv_articulo_exportacion iae WHERE iae.art_codigo_interno = ia.art_codigo)
         LEFT JOIN inv_articulo_cumplimiento cum ON cum.articuloId = ia.art_codigo 
         WHERE vc.ven_codigo = 686 AND imar.mar_requiere_doc_exportacion = 1 
         ORDER BY ia.art_descripcion ASC
  ```
- NUEVAMENTE PROBE CON ESTA OTRA CONSULTA Y ME DICE QUE TENGO UN ERROR EN MY SINTAXIS SQL

  ```
        SELECT * FROM vnt_cotizacion vc
        INNER JOIN vnt_detalle_cotizacion vdc ON vdc.dven_cotizacion = vc.ven_codigo
         INNER JOIN inv_articulo ia ON ia.art_codigo = vdc.dven_articulo 
         INNER JOIN inv_categoria icat ON icat.cat_codigo = ia.art_categoria_export 
         INNER JOIN inv_marca imar ON imar.mar_codigo = ia.art_marca 
         LEFT JOIN inv_categoria_export icex ON icex.id_categoria_export = icat.cat_codigo
          LEFT JOIN  (SELECT iae.art_onzas1, iae.art_onzas2, iae.art_mililitros, iae.art_gramos, iae.art_marker, iae.art_adress 
         FROM inv_articulo_exportacion iae)
         ON iae.art_codigo_interno = ia.art_codigo
         LEFT JOIN inv_articulo_cumplimiento cum ON cum.articuloId = ia.art_codigo 
         WHERE vc.ven_codigo = 686 AND imar.mar_requiere_doc_exportacion = 1 
         ORDER BY ia.art_descripcion ASC
  ```

Comment: Por favor no resumas los errores. Puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir el mensaje de error completo que te sale al usar la consulta que probaste

Comment: a ese join le falta el on....

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo Resolvi me faltaba poner un alias en la consulta, lo que necesitaba era usar una subconsulta en un join, me guia de este link : https://firebird21.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/usando-una-subconsulta-en-un-join/

```
SELECT * FROM vnt_cotizacion vc
INNER JOIN vnt_detalle_cotizacion vdc ON vdc.dven_cotizacion = vc.ven_codigo
INNER JOIN inv_articulo ia ON ia.art_codigo = vdc.dven_articulo 
INNER JOIN inv_categoria icat ON icat.cat_codigo = ia.art_categoria_export 
INNER JOIN inv_marca imar ON imar.mar_codigo = ia.art_marca 
LEFT JOIN inv_categoria_export icex ON icex.id_categoria_export = icat.cat_codigo
JOIN  (SELECT iae.art_codigo_interno art_cod_ex , iae.art_onzas1, iae.art_onzas2, iae.art_mililitros, iae.art_gramos, iae.art_marker, iae.art_adress 
FROM inv_articulo_exportacion iae) as exportacion
 ON exportacion.art_cod_ex = ia.art_codigo
LEFT JOIN inv_articulo_cumplimiento cum ON cum.articuloId = ia.art_codigo 
WHERE vc.ven_codigo = 686 AND imar.mar_requiere_doc_exportacion = 1 
ORDER BY ia.art_descripcion ASC
```